# Ruby, Tk and Ocra - very slow startup

Tags: ruby, startup, tk-toolkit, ocra

I'd like to deploy my Ruby application as an .exe file, for windows users. The application uses Tk for the GUI part.

Since I simply couldn't manage to succeed with rubyscript2exe I opted for ocra. Ocra works fine and builds a reasonable sized .exe. HOWEVER the application takes probably 10 seconds to start up. Even though it's really a quite simple tool.

Is there any way to improve startup-times? My guess is that the main issue is uncompressing the tk-libs on every startup...

Comment: Can you provide more details about the version of Ruby and ocra you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue with Tk, and it wouldn't work when using Ocra with InnoSetup.

I switched to Gtk, and now with Ocra + InnoSetup the GUI appears in 1-2 seconds rather than 10-20.

The reason is that Ocra with InnoSetup doesn't have to decompress the files into a temp directory, making it much faster to load once it's installed.
Gtk seems more compatible with Ocra, and it seems to load faster than Tk anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try building the executable with the --no-lzma option.
The resulting file will start faster (but still slow).